# JS: Mix-ins in JavaScript with Caching ? How does this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

So,

I am newbie JS Developer.

Mix-ins:

When i was going through

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

I could't understand difference between Topic 3 (With Options) and Topic 4 (Add Caching)

Quoting the ***"So maybe you’re concerned that this approach creates additional performance overhead because we’re redefining the same functions on every call."*** (first para under Adding Caching)

```
var asRectangle = (function () {

    console.log(this) // global this 

    function area() {
        console.log(this); // {length : 1, width: 2}
        return this.length * this.width
    }

    function grow() {
        this.length++;
        this.width++;
    }

    function shrink() {
        this.length--;
        this.width--;
    }

    return function () {
        this.area = area;
        this.grow = grow;
        this.shrink = shrink;
        return this;
    };

})();


var React = function (len, wid) {
    this.length = len;
    this.width = wid;
}

asRectangle.call(React.prototype); // What is the use of this?

var react = new React(1, 2);

react.area();
```

Questions:

1. As the above quote states, why function gets redefined every time?
2. How is caching implemented?
3. What asReactangle.Call() doing here?
4. How does this improves performance as the blog states?

P.S : I ran the code using Node.js -- So the global (this) printed the Node's global this.